# How to return multiple values from stored procedure within tsql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have an appointment table that contains four `datetime` columns:

```
AppointmentStart
AppointmentEnd
Arrival
Departure
```

Now the data is a mess, sometimes arrival and/or departure are null, in the future, in the past, all over the show. `AppointmentEnd` has even been found to be before `AppointmentStart`.

I've written a stored procedure to calculate a start and end time, and the length of the appointment.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Calcdates @ApptStart DATETIME,
                          @ApptEnd   DATETIME,
                          @PatArrive DATETIME,
                          @PatDepart DATETIME
AS
    DECLARE @CalcStart DATETIME
    DECLARE @CalcEnd DATETIME
    DECLARE @CalcLen INT

    -- CALCULATED STARTDATETIME
    SET @CalcStart = CASE
                       WHEN @PatArrive IS NULL THEN @ApptStart
                       WHEN @PatArrive IS NOT NULL THEN
                         CASE
                           WHEN @PatArrive BETWEEN Dateadd(MINUTE, -60, @ApptStart) AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @PatArrive
                           ELSE @ApptStart
                         END
                     END
    -- CALCUALTED ENDDATETIME
    SET @CalcEnd = CASE
                     WHEN @PatDepart IS NULL THEN
                       CASE
                         WHEN @ApptEnd BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @ApptEnd
                         ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, @ApptStart)
                       END
                     WHEN @PatDepart IS NOT NULL THEN
                       CASE
                         WHEN @PatDepart BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @PatDepart
                         ELSE
                           CASE
                             WHEN @ApptEnd BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @ApptEnd
                             ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, @ApptStart)
                           END
                       END
                   END
    -- CALCULATED LENGTH
    SET @CalcLen = Datediff(MINUTE, @CalcStart, @CalcEnd)
```

What I now need to do is figure out how to have this return values within my query.

i.e. this is what I currently have

```
SELECT PrimKey,
       Name,
       AppointmentStart,
       AppointmentEnd,
       PatArrive,
       PatDepart,
       Somehow have the results of the SP here
FROM   MyTable
```

What I want to do is call the SP within that query, and give me the calculated values for each record.

Does someone know how to do this? Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: What happens if you put that SQL statement inside your stored procedure? Surely it returns the recorset as required? If not, what is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have explained that better.  The query is part of another SP that does and ETL.  I just updated the question, hopefully that's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations for `CalcStart` and `CalcEnd` are dependent only on the data in the row, which is good. Only the calculation of `CalcLen` is dependent on another calculation. So, you can in-line the calculation of the first two (i.e. `CalcStart` and `CalcEnd`) in a CTE and then use their calculated values to get `CalcLen`, all in a single shot.

Try the following. All I did was take your final SELECT statement and replace the "Somehow have the results of the SP here" with the calculation of the start and end dates as columns instead of into variables. That combined query is the basis of the CTE, which is then selected from and now includes the calculated values of `CalcStart` and `CalcEnd`. At that point I just added the third calculation as another column.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT PrimKey,
          Name,
          AppointmentStart,
          AppointmentEnd,
          PatArrive,
          PatDepart,
          CASE
              WHEN PatArrive IS NULL THEN AppointmentStart
              WHEN PatArrive IS NOT NULL THEN
                   CASE
                       WHEN PatArrive BETWEEN Dateadd(MINUTE, -60, AppointmentStart)
                                AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, AppointmentStart)
                                     THEN PatArrive
                       ELSE AppointmentStart
                   END
              END AS [CalcStart],
          CASE
              WHEN PatDepart IS NULL THEN
                   CASE
                       WHEN AppointmentEnd BETWEEN AppointmentStart AND
                          Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, AppointmentStart) THEN AppointmentEnd
                       ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, AppointmentStart)
                   END
              WHEN PatDepart IS NOT NULL THEN
                   CASE
                       WHEN PatDepart BETWEEN AppointmentStart AND
                            Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, AppointmentStart) THEN PatDepart
                       ELSE
                           CASE
                               WHEN AppointmentEnd BETWEEN AppointmentStart
                                    AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, AppointmentStart)
                                    THEN AppointmentEnd
                               ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, AppointmentStart)
                           END
                       END
                   END AS [CalcEnd]
    FROM   MyTable
)
SELECT *, Datediff(MINUTE, [CalcStart], [CalcEnd]) AS [CalcLen]
FROM cte;
```

Just for future reference, there is also the option of creating an Inline TVF that takes in the 4 columns as input parameters, does the CTE just to get `[CalcStart]` and `[CalcEnd]`, and spits out those values plus the calculation of `[CalcLen]`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateDates (@AppointmentStart DATETIME,
                                @AppointmentEnd DATETIME,
                                @PatArrive DATETIME,
                                @PatDepart DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
         CASE
             WHEN @PatArrive IS NULL THEN @AppointmentStart
             WHEN @PatArrive IS NOT NULL THEN
                 CASE
                     WHEN @PatArrive BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, @AppointmentStart)
                             AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, @AppointmentStart)
                                      THEN @PatArrive
                     ELSE @AppointmentStart
                 END
             END AS [CalcStart],
         CASE
             WHEN @PatDepart IS NULL THEN
                 CASE
                     WHEN @AppointmentEnd BETWEEN @AppointmentStart AND
                        DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, @AppointmentStart) THEN @AppointmentEnd
                     ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @AppointmentStart)
                 END
             WHEN @PatDepart IS NOT NULL THEN
                 CASE
                     WHEN @PatDepart BETWEEN @AppointmentStart AND
                         DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, @AppointmentStart) THEN @PatDepart
                     ELSE
                         CASE
                             WHEN @AppointmentEnd BETWEEN @AppointmentStart
                                 AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, @AppointmentStart)
                                 THEN @AppointmentEnd
                             ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @AppointmentStart)
                         END
                     END
                 END AS [CalcEnd]
)
SELECT [CalcStart], [CalcEnd], DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [CalcStart], [CalcEnd]) AS [CalcLen]
FROM cte;
GO
```

The function would be used as follows:

```
SELECT mt.PrimKey,
       mt.Name,
       mt.AppointmentStart,
       mt.AppointmentEnd,
       mt.PatArrive,
       mt.PatDepart,
       dates.[CalcStart],
       dates.[CalcEnd],
       dates.[CalcLen]
FROM MyTable mt
CROSS APPLY CalculateDates(mt.AppointmentStart,
                           mt.AppointmentEnd,
                           mt.PatArrive,
                           mt.PatDepart) dates;
```

But there is no real need to go with the function over the inline CTE shown in the first example if you aren't going to use these calculations in multiple places. Also keep in mind that Inline TVFs are much more efficient than multiline TVFs (the style where you can perform multiple steps, inserting into a table variable, and RETURN that variable at the end), hence the need to re-use the CTE concept within the function.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that.  I've never encountered TVF before, I should start doing some research into it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table valued function and use it in the select statement(untested).

```
CREATE FUNCTION Calcdates (@ApptStart DATETIME,
                           @ApptEnd   DATETIME,
                           @PatArrive DATETIME,
                           @PatDepart DATETIME)
RETURNS @Calcdates TABLE (
  CalcStart DATETIME,
  CalcEnd   DATETIME,
  CalcLen   INT )
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @CalcStart DATETIME
      DECLARE @CalcEnd DATETIME
      DECLARE @CalcLen INT

      SET @CalcStart = CASE
                         WHEN @PatArrive IS NULL THEN @ApptStart
                         WHEN @PatArrive IS NOT NULL THEN
                           CASE
                             WHEN @PatArrive BETWEEN Dateadd(MINUTE, -60, @ApptStart) AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @PatArrive
                             ELSE @ApptStart
                           END
                       END
      -- CALCUALTED ENDDATETIME
      SET @CalcEnd = CASE
                       WHEN @PatDepart IS NULL THEN
                         CASE
                           WHEN @ApptEnd BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @ApptEnd
                           ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, @ApptStart)
                         END
                       WHEN @PatDepart IS NOT NULL THEN
                         CASE
                           WHEN @PatDepart BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @PatDepart
                           ELSE
                             CASE
                               WHEN @ApptEnd BETWEEN @ApptStart AND Dateadd(MINUTE, 480, @ApptStart) THEN @ApptEnd
                               ELSE Dateadd(MINUTE, 30, @ApptStart)
                             END
                         END
                     END
      -- CALCULATED LENGTH
      SET @CalcLen = Datediff(MINUTE, @CalcStart, @CalcEnd)

      INSERT INTO @Calcdates
      VALUES      (@CalcStart,@CalcEnd,@CalcLen)

      RETURN;
  END;

SELECT PrimKey,
       Name,
       AppointmentStart,
       AppointmentEnd,
       PatArrive,
       PatDepart,
       T.CalcStart,
       T.CalcEnd,
       T.CalcLen
FROM   MyTable
       CROSS apply Calcdates(AppointmentStart, AppointmentEnd, PatArrive, PatDepart) as T
```